# Which URLs produce Google Adsense revenue?

Tags: google-adsense

Is there a menu in Google AdSense that can let me know which URLs on my website are generating the most revenue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you have Google Analytics and Google AdSense linked, you can then go to the Content section in Analytics and view each page of your site along with the amount of revenue generated.

See [How do I link my AdSense account to Google Analytics?](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6084409?hl=en) in Google help.